# Bottom Navigation with Navigation Component Creates New Fragment

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-architecture-navigation, android-bottomnav

I have a `BottomNavigationView` which I've bound to NavController using

```
val navController: NavController by lazy {
    val navHostFragment =
        supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
    navHostFragment.navController
}

bottomNav?.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

The `bottomNav` has three menu items: **Home**, **Todos** and **Profile**. Where **Home** is made the default fragment by adding:

```
app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment"
```

So, the `NavController` creates a new instance for these `Fragments` like so.

| Fragment | First Visit | Further Visit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Home | New Instance | Re-use instance |
| Todos | New Instance | New Instance |
| Profile | New Instance | New Instance |

Even though the **Todos** and **Profile** `Fragments` are created again, their states are still restored. However, the `Fragment`'s `View` (created from `onCreateView()`) does not get attached and instead the previously created Fragment's `View` is used. So, I cannot make any changes to the UI (or at least they have no effect).

The way I see it, I can solve the problem in one of the two ways:

1. Either I make sure existing instance of `Fragments` are reused. OR
2. Make sure the newly created `View` is bound to the `View Hierarchy`.

So, my questions are, how do I make sure that the latest inflated UI is attached or how do I reuse the existing `Fragment`. Am I missing something obvious here?

Note: I'm using the latest navigation component version **2.4.0-beta02**. Which contains Multiple BackStack Support.

Answer (score 0):

So, the mistake I was making was that I was re-inflating my layout in my `Fragments`. Reusing the already inflated layout solved this for me.